# JavaScript convert a String that contains the code into a object

Tags: javascript

on my current project I have a variables.js which contains all variables like theme colors.

I want to put this complete variables.js into a Database but its rly long, and I would prefer to put it into the database as a string to keep it easy for upcomming changes.

Is there any way, to make that this string which looks like the example down below get converted into a object that would work exactly like that down below.

Here a example whats inside the variables.js

```
export default {
    faq_size                          : 5,
    debug_show_php_errors             : true,
    debug_disable_captcha             : false,
    discord_color                     : "#7289DA",
    theme                             : {primary: "deep-purple darken-4", secondary: "deep-purple accent-1",},
    currencies                        : ["€", "$", "₽", "£", "¥"],
    languages                         : [
        {
            lang   : 'en',
            code   : 'US',
            country: 'English',
        },
        {
            lang   : 'de',
            code   : 'DE',
            country: 'Deutsch',
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify() yet?

Comment: Put JSON in your database, not text. Most databases do support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import data from 'variables.js'

// convert data to string 
let dataInStringFormat = JSON.stringify(data);
// now you can save this in any database you want.

// convert string to object again
let data = JSON.parse(dataInStringFormat);
```

Comment: I'll also thought about that but with that way, but the code is still in json format when I'm putting it into a text field to edit it. Do you also know there a solution how I can make that it looks like a normal code and when applying it it looks then like the json?

Comment: you can save it to a NoSQL database that preserves its type. You can use MongoDB for it.

Comment: Ok I found a solution for that what I'm looking for. I've had to use more parameters on stringify
JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);